Python console in Taipy
I've been trying to create a section in my Taipy application in which I print the content of the underlying Python console, to have a read-only application log that stays up-to-date in real time.
So far the only solution I found is to write the log messages to file (e.g. with the logging module), and periodically read the file and print its content in a text control. I'm sure there is a more intelligent way to do it. Any advice?

can't you send text directly to text control without using log ? maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run.
